# Ubuntu 14.04, Kingston micro-SD 32GB, Toshiba laptop - the SD card doesn't work!

Tags: 14.04, sd-card, toshiba-satellite

So after I have not been helped with the MTP issues I still have to deal with concerning my Sony Xperia U android, I hope it will be possible to fix this one at least.

**The issue is simple, I put my SD card into the adapter, then I insert it as a whole into the slot carved in my laptop, and the OS simply fails to notice it, I cannot even see the device's name in the file manager of the OS, nada.**

I am a bit surprised that there's an inhumane amount of people who never actually get any help with these issues, am I the only one who is aware of the fact that these specific problems are and ever would be a huge, monstrous drawback to any operating system? It's just copying files, I don't want the system to endow me with the deepest secrets of the universe, the knowledge of the arcane, I just want to COPY files, things that actually worked back then in 2008 (I think), using Ubuntu 8. They not only worked, but they worked splendidly...

Comment: This is a common problem with SD card slots on Ubuntu machines. As far as I know, there might be no way to solve it.

Comment: Hmm, so basically, it is impossible to have a Linux platform without a Microsoft platform installed on your computer? You just have to switch to Windows in order to copy files? Even death sounds more pleasant to me than that.

Comment: It happens for me on my Toshiba Satellite A70 running 12.04. Some platforms are supported, but most old/very new laptops don't work. If you really need the SD card, buy a reader (you can probably find them pretty cheap). For me, there is no solution (Satellite A70 is a 2004 laptop).

Comment: It's a great question though.

Comment: In my country, nothing is cheap, except for the wages, of course. But it really does look like there are only two options: either to try the newest version (of which I am rightfully afraid, as Ubuntu seems to deteriorate with every upgrade) or to switch to Microsoft again, which I hate more than anything, so that won't work as well. I shall install some Windows platform in order to perform functions Ubuntu is quite oblivious of, no matter how simple they appear to be.

Comment: The problem regarding hardware support has to do with the manufacturers, not the OS.

Comment: Prior to the instance within the bounds of which I started writing, I had already been quite aware of the fact. Manufacturers and Microsoft get along real well, that is quite an explicit statement, but it is still a problem of the OS. I haven't been trying to blame anyone, I just marvel at there not being enough apparent zeal to fix especially those common issues that pertain to a large group of users, like copying files.

Comment: It would be quite different if it happened to be impossible to fix the issues that we had been discussing, however, I do not think that is the case. But still, I could be wrong, as I don't really see into the intertwined cobweb of sw-hw communication. That's why I wonder.

Comment: The vast majority of the MMC/SD card readers is supported. Actually I never found one that wasn't. If yours requires  proprietary drivers, how exactly is it something Ubuntu should fix?  Or can (without breaking the law by reverse engineering something)?

Comment: Wait, this requires an explanation. Please, correct me if my understanding of the matter is not quite accurate. The manufacturers create, either purposefully or coincidentally, or out of sheer carelessness, components that refuse to run smoothly with the Linux platforms, whereas as a consequence a whole lot of issues arise to pose as an obstacle to the Linux users. However, as if it were not bad enough, the companies do not allow the Linux team to penetrate the secrets of the inner workings of these very components in order to help them fix it all?

Comment: One more question, if I may, what exactly prevents Linux from solving it the same way Microsoft does? I have never had any problem with Windows back then when I was still using it, except for the ones we are all familiar with, yet the specific devices that I cannot force into working with Ubuntu have always worked with Microsoft. I guess it's about money, which would consequently and subsequently mean better relations with the manufacturers, but I am often quite off the mark, so if I cannot solve the problem anyhow, I would at least like to know why.